# how can an item use full width of screen minus 60 pixels?

Tags: css, width

[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/)

I have some navigation on the left side of the screen so i set the body width to 100%.

the navigation width is 60px. the extra div i want to go from 60px from the left side to the end of the right side of the screen.

my problem is that it always comes out to the same width of the body plus 60px and i have an x-scroll on the bottom of the screen.

//this is on left side with width 60px

```
left:0;
position:fixed;
width:60px;
height:100%;
```

//this is between the navigation and right side of screen but should take up the entire width.

```
background:black;
width:100%;
height:100px;
margin-left:60px;
```

How can i display something on the left side of the screen that is 60px wide and then have a div that connects that to the right side of the screen without overextending with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need a fixed-fluid layout which has been extensively documented.  The fixed part should be 60px in width and the fluid part should take the rest of the width.  Take a look at the [dynamic drive](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C13/) for some inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you may want to add this to your `body`'s css: `overflow-x:hidden`, which would cut off the excess 60px on the right and prevent the scrollbar from appearing. However, content in the div may be cut off too. It really depends on what you are placing in the div.

Comment: the content will appear based on how wide the div is so if the div is cut off then the content inside the div may be cut off. :(

Comment: Unfortunately then, you probably can't achieve your goal with this method. It is nearly impossible to line things up right when combining absolute and relative values. You'll probably want to rethink the problem and decide on another solution. This is why computer science is all about problem solving :)

Answer (score 0):

See, we always have one solution to use `table` for these scenarios but my assumption is you don't want to use the table. Keeping `divs` in our design we can set the display property of the divs as table to make it work. Please find the solution fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/86/).

This works as you want and does not bring a horizontal scroll to the right main content part as well. Hope this helps.